# How to properly iterate over a double

Tags: c++, loops, floating-point, double

I'm iterating over `t` like this

```
double dt = 0.1, t;
double tmax = 100;
for (t = 0; t <= tmax; t += dt) { /*do something*/ }
```

If `dt` is 0.1, as here, everything works as it should and the step is executed for `t = 100`. But if I decrease the step, for example `dt = 0.001`, the last step is not executed.

How should I properly iterate over doubles?

Comment: One idea came to my mind. What about doing `for (t = 0; t < tmax + dt; t += dt)` ?

Answer (score 5):

Iterate over an integer and use a start-step formula to get each double value.

```
double dt = 0.1, t;
double tmax = 100;
int i, n = (int)(tmax / dt); // n: check your rounding or specify explicitly.
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) { t = 0/*start*/ + dt * i; /*do something*/ }
```

Comment: I think `n` in the third line and `nt` in the fourth line should be the same identifier.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice. also i used the wrong comparison `<`

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine, and the behavior is expected. Ok, not expected, but explainable due to how floating point numbers work. Look here http://floating-point-gui.de/ In case the link disappears one day, google "what programmers should know about floating point" - I'm sure it'll be cached somewhere!

Comment: More literature: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Minimizing_the_effect_of_accuracy_problems (Minimizing_the_effect_of_accuracy_problems)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
for (t = 0; t <= tmax; t += dt) { /*do something*/ }
```

write:

```
double i;
for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i += 1.0) { 
  t = i / 10.0;
  /*do something */
}
```

With this pattern, the loop body will be executed exactly 1001 times and each value of `t` will be the nearest `double` approximation of the number you intended (in particular, the 11th value will be 1 exactly, the 31th value will be 3 exactly, …).

Your version does not work well because simple decimal numbers such as 0.1 or 0.01 are not representable exactly in binary floating-point.

If you are willing to adapt the number of points to the fact that you are using binary floating-point, simply use a power of two and all will be well:

```
for (t = 0; t <= 100.0; t += 1.0 / 64.0) { /*do something*/ }
```

Comment: That doesn't allow for arbitraty `dt`. What if `dt` is `Math.PI/10`? (Practical example: drawing a 20-gon)

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Your answer has a systematic bias in that it always “does something” for `t` containing `i * 0.1`, whereas the intention was `i`/10. This systematic bias can be avoided in the conditions of the question, because 10, 100 and 1000 are exactly representable. When neither `dt` nor its inverse are exactly representable, the simplest solution is to use multiplication.

Comment: Whatever integer `i` is, `i*dt` is always the closest IEEE-754 float to the ideal value in case `1/dt` is ideally integer. Exactly the same as `i*10` if `dt=1/10`.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus No: 3 * 0.1 != 3 / 10.0. The latter is `0x1.3333333333333p-2`, the former is `0x1.3333333333334p-2`. The latter is a better approximation.

Comment: I see what you mean. if `1/dt` isn't integer, the bias adds up. In some cases you can multiply-divide. You can iterate over integer `i`, multiply by `Math.PI` then divide by `10`. The result still has round-off errors tough, but less than multiplying with `Math.PI/10`. It's up to the user to decide if usability or accuracy is most important.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus It really depends. It could coincidentally be the case that π/10 falls very close to a `double`, closer than π is relatively to its closest `double`. In this case, using the `double` for π/10 directly would be better than trying sophisticated tricks.

Comment: you're going backwards now, stating things I clearly knew all along.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64552/discussion-between-mark-jeronimus-and-pascal-cuoq).